# Can't displaying images of ASP.NET charts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, charts, asp.net-charts

I am following line by line the tutorial that exists [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235117/ASP-NET-4-0-Chart-Control), in order to create an ASP chart at my MVC 4 website.

For the beginning it just includes this into the aspx code

```
 <asp:Chart ID="cTestChart" runat="server">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1">
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">

            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

if we modify the code and put points like this

```
<asp:Chart ID="cTestChart" runat="server">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Testing" YValueType="Int32">

            <Points>
                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 1" YValues="10" />
                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 2" YValues="20" />

                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 3" YValues="30" />
                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 4" YValues="40" />

            </Points>
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>

    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

However, my code compiles successfully, and it displays a broken picture image instead of the chart. When I press f12 at chrome, it shows an ERROR 404 on the picture. I have also tried other ways to diplay my chart but all the ways had the same result. The project is a new project, and I have not changed anything.

Can you please help me with that?